# How do I defeat the elevator Necromorphs?

Tags: dead-space-2

I have been forced to take a particularly large and long elevator ride up to some unknown destination. To the surprise of absolutely nobody, I was attacked on the elevator ride by a bunch of Necromorphs.

These ones, however, instead of rushing at me recklessly, break through the glass on the side and then slowly poke me to death using their grotesque limb tentacle things.

I seem to be struggling with this fight a lot. I thought I was inflicting some damage on them by shooting their limbs, but more just keep on coming and eventually the pokes overwhelm.

How I defeat this boss?

Which weapons are particularly effective?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These Necromorphs have a few stages:

1. Choosing a window and displaying their tentacles (weak point).
2. Delaying for a few seconds to give you a chance to attack.
3. - If shot:   Delay for a few more seconds and retreat.
   - Otherwise: Attack and goto 2.

I remember having some trouble with the elevator, but here are some tips:

- Keep on the lookout constantly. You need to spot the Necromorph the instant he shows himself in a window.
- Shooting a tentacle will cause the Necromorph to give up on it's attack, even if you do not do enough damage to remove a limb.
- If there are multiple Necromorphs ready to attack, shoot each Necromorph once with a low damage gun such as the pulse rifle. Focus your fire on the last Necromorph, as the others will not attack and will give you time.
- Don't be afraid to take your time. If you turn around and see a Necromorph that may have been sitting there for a while, just shoot him once and look for others, focusing on him only once you have confirmed that there aren't any others ready to attack.
- Just a theory, but I believe the fight is time-based rather than enemy count based, as you should reach the end of the trip with a small amount of oxygen left. This emphasizes the above point, as your focus should be staying alive rather than killing all of the Necromorphs as quickly as possible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's not a theory, it's a fact, and there is a trophy on the PS3 version associated to it.

Answer (score 4):

I remember this part.  It was hard, especially because I was playing on Zealot and had no health / health packs.

The general trick that I eventually used to win was to hang out near the elevator door and quickly scan left/right.  The moment I saw one, I would either hit it with stasis and use the pulse rifle to saw a leg off (they are actually pretty weak if you hit the right spot) or just stay out of range.  The tentacle only reaches about to the center of the elevator, meaning that if you are by the door, most of their attacks can't reach you.

The ones that it is very important to spot and hit early are the ones that appear right next to the door.  Hit them with stasis and saw a leg off quickly, and then look the other direction; they like to attack from behind you as you are dealing with one of their buddies.

Also, immediately after killing one they usually drop something that you can grab using kinesis.  I got a few health packs this way.

Expect it to take quite a few tries.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I remembered this one. It starts out with just one tentacle thing, but they start to spawn faster and faster. There's not really any "trick" to it, just like any boss fight: Shoot the yellow things on the tentacles.

I used the line cutter a lot and had great success with it. The beam weapon had an alternative fire where you hit the ground and damage everyone close to you. It can be upgraded to do stasis damage too, this would probably help a lot in this fight (as well as in similar fights later on).

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember this elevator, which could mean it was really short and/or easy.

But, my guess is, those necromorphs does have a weak point, wich is the yellow place on their body. If they are using tentacle, you should try cutting them with the laser cutter, it should do the trick.

I'll reinstall this evening, maybe you'll have some more feedback tomorrow...